# Gradle run flywayMigration during unit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, gradle, flyway

I am working on spring boot/gradle project and for some reason, Gradle run flywayMigrate task during Unit testing, so it failed with.

```
Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate. Connection refused
```

I run tests with *./gradlew clean test*

My *build.gradle* file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'nu.studer.jooq' version '4.1'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "6.2.0"
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

ext {
    dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"
    dbUsername = 'admin'
    dbPassword = 'admin'
    dbDriver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
    dbSchema = 'public'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.9'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    jooqRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.9'
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq'
}

test {
    useJUnit()
}

jooq {
    version = '3.11.0'
    edition = 'OSS'
    sample(sourceSets.main) {
        jdbc {
            driver = dbDriver
            url = dbUrl
            user = dbUsername
            password = dbPassword
            schema = dbSchema
        }
        generator {
            database {
                inputSchema = dbSchema
                excludes = 'databasechangelog|databasechangeloglock'
            }
            generate {
                relations = false
                deprecated = false
                records = true
                immutablePojos = false
                fluentSetters = false
                javaTimeTypes = true
            }
            target {
                directory = 'build/generated/sources/jooq'
                packageName = 'com.test.generated.models'
            }
        }
    }
}

flyway {
    url = dbUrl
    user = dbUsername
    password = dbPassword
    schemas = [dbSchema]
    locations = ["filesystem:$project.projectDir/src/main/resources/db/migration"]
}

generateSampleJooqSchemaSource.dependsOn flywayMigrate
```

I don't try to run integration tests. Just units, so I don't need db connection there. FlywayMigration work well with *gradlew bootRun*

Comment: assuming you have an application.properties you will want to create one in the test resources like the one in the "main" project. on the application properties of the test project you can disable flyway with "spring.flyway.enabled=false"

Answer (score 1):

The flyway from the "build.gradle" is not the one that is being ran.

Spring boot auto configures flyway because you have the flyway core in the dependencies.
By default it uses your application.properties / application.yml to read the jdbc parameters.

So my suggestion for you would be to create a new application properties on the resources of the tests and set `spring.flyway.enabled=false`.

References:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/plugins/springboot